# How to display inputs of for associated object with object is created on new form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm not sure the topic will have the right meaning what I want, but I don't know how to explain. I'm building online examination app. To easy for explain problem, I focus to 6 tables:

1. Courses: **`has_many`** topics
2. Topics: **`belongs_to`** course
3. Questions: **`belongs_to`** topic, **`has_many`** general_exams, **through:** :general_questions
4. GeneralExams: **`has_many`** questions, **`through:`** general_questions, **`belongs_to`** user, **`belongs_to`** course, **`has_many`** exam
5. GeneralQuestions: **`belongs_to`** question, **`belongs_to`** general_exam
6. Exam: **`belongs_to`** general exam, **`belongs_to`** user

This is columns in table GeneralExam:

```
name,description,semester,number_question,duration,used, user_id, course_id
```

What I want to do now, is create a general exam, and can specific a number of questions for each topic of course. Example, I have a **course named** "Database" has 3 topics: A,B,C. Now I want to create general exam for **"Database" course**. I want to specific when create general exam:

- 5 question for topic A
- 6 question for topic B
- 7 question for topic C

These questions I get random from these topic. I have build a form for create general exam, but I don't know how to get topics of course on the form, and make a field for input number question for each topic. So is there some way to list topics on new form of general exam and each topic will have a field to type in number question will be got random for that topic? Or I need to create a new table to store that information?

Comment: What exactly do you plan to do with the input numbers? Are you trying to determine how many question fields to render in the form? Otherwise, if this is for db performance reasons, why not user [counter cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column)?

Comment: I want, with input `number` of question for topics, I will get random `number` of questions of those topics for a GE. I also want to statistic then.

Comment: Because one general exam will be generated exams for students, and I want to statistic number of question of each topic in exams of students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I will do...

a database should be concider its "flexability".
for that, all information store in diffrent table..
then for the speed of retriving data.. build some relation table to display information..
(depends on how many people going to use your system)

so....form top down....

teacher table(one teacher can teach many coursee)..every thing started here)
->
courses table (this is the base of all others)
-----------------folowing may start cross referance..
-->
topic table
--->
g-exam table Big Question table  may at same level
-->
g-question table should be at bottom level (may ref back to g-exam and Big-Q)

(Don't need to save teacher info or topic info since it is twwo-level up..
but you can still store those info for fast retriving data..
but remember ..
if you need to change info after information has been stored...
simple is better...

Comment: I think I need to store info of teacher and topic, If don't, I can not know courses belongs to who, and topics belong to what course.First thinking, I think I don't need to create new table to store number of questions of each topic of course of general exam, because it just a number for me to get questions of that topics, and questions already know which topic it belong to. But maybe I need to create new table for fast retrieving data. I will think about this, thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

I just go over my answer...
I found one mistake I said..
I should have said :you don't need to save teacher or topic info in the g-question table..
g-question table only save question-key and g-exam-key
and question table and g-exam table save topic-key
.....and referance back to top level..

and create a fast retriving table for fast access,which may update on daily basis
(ex:to show teacher name,top name...etc  since these table linked by "key" not name

sorry not saying it correctly

Comment: g-exam already save course-key, how it save topic-key if it not know many topic one course has?